# Error while fetching website source using C++,libcurl in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, libcurl

I'm trying to fetch website source using C++ and libcurl in Qt 4.8. I'm new to Qt and C++.
However, Im getting an error message

**Error Message -**

```
Starting C:*****.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:*****.exe exited with code  -1073741819
```

```
#include <curl/include/curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


static size_t data_write(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    if(userp)
    {
        std::ostream& os = *static_cast<std::ostream*>(userp);
        std::streamsize len = size * nmemb;
        if(os.write(static_cast<char*>(buf), len))
            return len;
    }

    return 0;
}

CURLcode curl_read(const std::string& url, std::ostream& os, long timeout = 30)
{
    CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl)
    {
        if(CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &data_write))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, &os))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str())))
        {
            code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return code;
}

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);


    if(CURLE_OK == curl_read("http://google.com", std::cout))
    {
    // Web page successfully written to standard output (console?)
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Whats the problem with the code above ?

P.S - Above code is not mine.

Comment: You want SO debug it for you?

Comment: I want to know how you got double scroll bars on the code window.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: The code is OK. Did you link to curl DLL without putting the DLL in your PATH or the same folder of the exe?

Comment: The cURL folder is in the same project folder and i linked it by putting LIBS += "C:**********\curl\lib\libcurldll.a" in .pro

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother using external libraries use what Qt has got. And it has plenty !

Here is a simple exemple on how you can get a webpage source!

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onfinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),mgr,SLOT(deleteLater()));

    mgr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));

}

void MainWindow::onfinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QByteArray bts = rep->readAll();
    QString str(bts);
    QMessageBox::information(this,"sal",str,"ok");

}
```

And if you want to create a blocking function check out this tutorial over [here](http://www.erata.net/qt-boost/synchronous-http-request/).

Hope it helps!